# Express 4.x redirect

Tags: node.js, http, express

I need some help understanding how this redirect works (and why isn't doing what I think it's supposed to do):

Problem: 
I have an HTML page with a "logout" button that triggers a jQuery snippet:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:8000/chat",
        data: {logout_msg: "get_out"},
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {

        },
        dataType:"json"
});
```

The button works, I catch the "POST" in my NodeJS server, here:

```
app.post('/chat', (req, res) => {
   req.session.destroy((error) => {
      if (!error) {
         res.redirect("/login");
      } else {
         console.log(error);
      }
});
```

The response is received by the browser:
[image: web-console]

But there is no web-page redirect. The browser won't load the other redirect page. I tried this in Firefox & Chrome. Both behave the same way, so I assume it's something in my code. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only "redirect" the request of jquery. If you want to open an other page in the Browser, then send the logout request with an HTML form or use location.href = '...' in the success handler.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'd like the redirect to be triggered by the server not by the client. I thought about creating a local redirect in the $.ajax function (if succesful), but in my ideal scenario the server will force the browser to redirect. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks, so what you're suggesting is that the POST request from the browser has to be from a form. The ajax call won't do it? In my mind a <form type=POST> and an $.ajax of type "POST" should be treated the same way, right?

Comment: trying your hidden form suggestion - if I understand you correctly, the "form" is mandatory. So only a form's URL will be automatically redirected by the browser. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need JQuery to do simple log out.

Just add in HTML
`<form action="/logout" method="post">`

And in server side

```
app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
   req.session.destroy((error) => {
      if (!error) {
         res.redirect("/login");
      } else {
         console.log(error);
      }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right...So what is the problem of GET me out of this site? why use post? we can change the form. General idea is the same. Forget about JQuery and use native redirect. Done. Just add `form action post :D` lul.